# What does a testing internship at CIBC ( the Bank ) entail?

Tags: testing

The job title is "Test Analyst-Batch Testing". I know I will be doing black and gray box testing. I a little unsure on gray box testing. Also it seems like heavy scripting will be involved. My question for people in the software testing industry. What kind of software will I be testing as an intern at CIBC ( the Bank )? What will I learn? And How it  will be handy for advancing my career?

Comment: Can you clarify CIBC to be the bank?

Comment: If you can give more detail, the not-programming-related tag can go away.. this is a programming position, yes?

Comment: I wanted to know what kind of programming I will be doing in this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it (without supplied links to the description) you will be testing testing, which could be neat.

If you are doing what your description says and checking / ensuring the quality of batch tests that an analyst runs, wow. You will not only be picking the brains of economy and market gurus, you will be helping to ensure that the results of mad scientist scenarios are as accurate as they can be. If I'm correct, you can assume:

1. You will be treated very well during your time there, perhaps as indispensable.
2. Knowledge of market voodoo is never bad, even if you have sworn off investments and stock markets as the root of all evil.
3. I don't know what kind of degree you are getting, but a little background in AI never hurt anyone. Its a good chance to think beyond the walls of the box that contain you.

As for your career? We go to work for two reasons.. one being personal esteem, the other being monetary compensation. I think this position is going to boost #1 quite a bit .. while helping to boost #2.

But, I suppose, its all at how you look at things. It pays to not be so picky early on.

Comment: I am in software engineering.